# Grep exact match string with spaces as variable

Tags: awk, grep

I have:

```
file.csv
```

Which contains

```
2,1,"string with spaces",3,4,5
2,1,"some other string",3,4,5
2,1,"string with spaces more than this",3,4,5
2,1,"yet another",3,4,5
2,1,"string with spaces too",3,4,5
```

When I do this:

`grep '"string with spaces",' file.csv`

It produces the desired out come which is:

```
2,1,"string with spaces",3,4,5
```

Now I need to do this in a while loop:

```
while read p; do

    grep '"$p",' file.csv

done < list.txt
```

Where:

```
list.txt
```

contains:

```
string with spaces
yet another
```

And my desired output is:

```
2,1,"string with spaces",3,4,5
2,1,"yet another",3,4,5
```

The problem is that my while loop comes back empty, or matches partially. How do I loop through `list.txt` & get my desired output?

Comment: Doing this by a loop calling `grep` repeatedly is **extremely** inefficient, you could do it all in one call to awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk` this should be an easy one for it.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($4 in a)' list.txt FS="[,\"]" file.csv
```

OR(as per Ed sir's comment to make field separator as comma and keep it clearer, one could try following)

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a["\""$0"\""];next} $3 in a' list.txt file.csv
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2,1,"string with spaces",3,4,5
2,1,"yet another",3,4,5
```

Comment: It should be `awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a["\""$0"\""];next} $3 in a' list.txt file.csv` to avoid errors when the quoted field contains commas

Comment: @EdMorton, sure Ed sir, added it now, thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Hmm, actually you'd need to use FPAT (or a different approach (e.g. with match($0,/"[^"]*"/)) to make it robust, even with the change I suggested it'd still fail if the quoted field contained commas.

Comment: @EdMorton, sorry sir, I don't have FPAT` since awk is old, if you could edit my answer will be grateful to you.

Comment: Not worthwhile since the OP already accepted a different answer.

Comment: @EdMorton I made an error in accepting the answer from @marcus. I went to implement his solution & it worked. However, my `list.txt` has 27k lines & then `file.csv` has 1,000k lines. `grep` was going super slow. I came back here & found your answer that @ravindersingh13 added to his answer. And yours worked in less than 5 seconds. I don't understand how awk works, but my solution with `grep` may have taken days.

Answer (score 2):

Your string quoting is all using single quotes `'` which does not do any interpolation of the `$p` variable. Changing it to `grep '"'"$p"'",' file.csv` will solve the problem. The key is that here the variable interpolation is done inside of double quotes `"` and then concatenated with the strings containing actual double quote `"` characters.

A more (or less, depending on your point of view) readable version could look like this: `grep "\"$p\"," file.csv`

Comment: This works  perfectly. I like the `grep "\"$p\"," file.csv` version, as it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep -Ff strings.txt file.csv
```

This should get you far enough.