# Bash - More efficient way to process csv file than grep

Tags: bash, grep

**Updated**

I have a file (`file.txt`) with a list of words:

```
apple
banana
cherry
orange
pineapples
```

I have a csv file (`data.csv`) that contains lots of data:

```
1,"tasty apples",3,5
23,"iphone app",5,12
1,"sour grapes",3,5
23,"banana apple smoothie",5,12
1,"cherries and orange shortage",3,5
23,"apple iphone orange cover",5,12
3,"pineapple cherry bubble gum",13,5
5,"pineapples are best frozen",22,33
```

I want to append the match from file like this (`output.csv`):

```
1,"tasty apples",3,5,""
23,"iphone app",5,12,""
1,"sour grapes",3,5,""
23,"banana apple smoothie",5,12,"apple+banana"
1,"cherries and orange shortage",3,5,"orange"
23,"apple iphone orange cover",5,12,"apple+orange"
3,"pineapple cherry bubble gum",13,5,"cherry"
5,"pineapples are best frozen",22,33,"pineapples"
```

I can this with `grep`, but in order to do this, I have to use a `while` loop with `if` statements and process text files.

The problem with doing this is that file.txt has about 500 lines, and data.csv has 330,000 lines. My script would work, however it may take days to complete.

I'm wondering is there a more efficient way to do this than my method?

Comment: Why are you back to considering a loop calling grep? Use awk again, just like in the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55184213/1745001).

Comment: `awk` would be a better choice. A more efficient way would be to not use a bash script at all, but rather some other language, like Python or whatever.

Comment: Python or anything else wouldn't be more efficient than awk unless MAYBE for some of the more esoteric possible CSV contents (e.g. nested newlines within fields).

Comment: @Lou if your quoted fields can contain newlines, commas, or double quotes then include those in your sample input/output. Also include fruits like pineapple and grapefruit whose names contain other fruits in your  input/output so we can see how you want those handled. Finally - clarify your rules for handling plurals because it's not clear at all why `apple` matches `apples` but `cherry` doesn't match `cherries`.

Comment: @EdMorton - it partially matches the string, but not varations. So, it will match apple, because this is a partial match to apples, but doesn't match cherries, because it doesn't partially (grep style) match cherry. Yes, the quoted field may contain a comma, but not another quote (single or double) and not a new line within the quoted cells within the csv. Will edit to show different fruits now.

Comment: So should `apple` match `pineapple` since that's a partial match too just like `apples` is? And `grape` should match `grapes` and `grapefruit`? Please cover all your use cases with your example, not just the most basic sunny day cases.

Comment: @EdMorton I was able to test your answered script tst.awk before you pulled it, that works exactly the way I need it to work. I'm looking at the output of that & it works flawlessly in a matter of seconds. I was multitasking, answered your question, saw your script, tried it & it works as expected. Please post again & I will accept answer. Amazing work.

Comment: It won't work for some cases you've said in comments can happen but haven't included in your example (e.g. commas within the quoted fields) so I've deleted it until you post a more comprehensive and realistic example that we can consider and test against.

Comment: @EdMorton You're right, pineapple does wreck the script. I just edited the OP, please see above.

Comment: grep is about as efficient as you can possibly get. **A loop calling grep**, by contrast, is horrible practice and should never be done by anyone. You aren't showing us the what and why of that loop, though, so we're not in a position to say anything useful.

Comment: If you really-really wanted to stick with bash alone, just to prove it can be done, you could try using associative arrays in bash 4.  Read the first file in line by line and assign the strings to an associative array, then split the lines of the second file by commas, strip quotes and split the second column by spaces.  Look up the words in the associative array and reconstruct the output.

Comment: You **still** haven't included commas in the quoted field even though you've told us in a comment that can happen and I specifically mentioned that would break some solutions and so was important to include in your example. And now you have more output lines than you have input. Please take a second to really **think** about the example you're providing and then try again. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: `data.csv` & `output.csv` now match. To simply this, I can just clean the file to strip out the lines that contain `,` within the field. Thanks for the help & walking me through all this.

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS qw{ csv };

open my $f1, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
my @fruits;
chomp, push @fruits, $_ while <$f1>;
my %order;
@order{@fruits} = 0 .. $#fruits;

my $regex = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } @fruits;

csv(
    in          => 'data.csv1',
    eol         => "\n",
    on_in       => sub {
        my @matches;
        push @matches, $1 while $_[1][1] =~ /\b($regex)\b/g;
        push @{ $_[1] }, join '+',
                         sort { $order{$a} <=> $order{$b} }
                         @matches;
    },
);
```

Unfortunately, [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS) can't quote the last field if it doesn't contain a special character (or without quoting all the fields). If `file.txt` doesn't contain double quotes and commas, though, you add them easily:

```
perl ... | sed 's/,\([^,"]*\)$/,"\1"/'
```

Comment: `data.csv1` should be `data.csv` in your script. Also, I get an error message of `Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at tmp.pl line 22.` and then another 
`Wide character in print at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26/IO/Handle.pm line 159.` Any idea why these errors?

Comment: `data.csv1` was copied from the question. About the "unitialized" warning: maybe you have an empty line in the `file.txt`? The "Wide character" means you simplified your samples too much - your real data contain non-ASCII characters, so you need to tell Perl which encoding to use.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want that last field quoted? The "+" has no special meaning in CSV, so does not need quotation and neither does an empty field.
Text::CSV_XS does support quotation of empty fields or quotation of all fields, but not yet quotation of all non-numeric fields.
Based on choroba's answer, which allows the last field to be "apple+apple+orange", which is not clearly defined in the OP if that is wanted, I'd write it like this:

```perl
use 5.14.1;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );
use Data::Peek;

chomp (my @fruits = do { local @ARGV = "file.txt"; <> });

my %order;
@order{@fruits} = 0 .. $#fruits;

my $regex = join "|", sort { length $b <=> length $a } @fruits;

csv (
    in          => "data1.csv",
    eol         => "\n",
    quote_empty => 1,
    on_in       => sub {
        push @{$_[1]}, join "+" =>
            sort { $order{$a} <=> $order{$b} }
            keys %{{map { $_ => 1 }
                    ($_[1][1] =~ m/\b($regex)\b/g)}};
        },
    );
```